# Сортирование в кортеж

Tags: python, сортировка

Вводятся числа, их не более 1000, каждое число в диапазоне от 10^-9 до 10^9. Надо вывести кортеж из этих чисел в отсортированном порядке. Запрещено использовать встроенное форматирование. **Пример ввода: 10 5 20. Вывод: (5, 10, 20)**

[Вот мой неработающий код](http://cs624727.vk.me/v624727250/3145/kRvHZJdyq5g.jpg)

Суть в том, что я создаю функцию, которая ищет минимальный элемент в массиве и добавляет его в кортеж. Но, к сожалению, не работает. Подскажите, как подправить программу, чтобы заработала.

Comment: Только, заметил, что в функцию надо добавить удаление элемента, но даже с ним не работает

Comment: [вот ответ, который не использует встроенное форматирование](http://hashcode.ru/questions/362220#362365)

Answer (score 3):

[`print(tuple(sorted(map(int, "10 5 20".split()))))`](http://ideone.com/Q11bpV) -> `(5, 10, 20)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 6]
t = []

for j in range(len(a)):
    c = a[0]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if c > a[i]:
            c = a[i]
    t.append(c)
    a.remove(c)

print(t)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.
____
a.remove(c) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove' выдает такую ошибку.
____
И квадратные скобки вроде как не кортеж + здесь и пробелы будут учитываться.

Comment: Из документации: Tuples are immutable.
Т.е. кортежы неизменяемые.
Если тебе нужен на выходе кортеж, можешь преобразовать из списка.
Задача сортировки стояла из одного списка выбирать наименьшее, достать его и записать в другой список, насколько я понял.
Проблемы с input() я здесь не решал.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = tuple(sorted([i for i in (10, 5, 20)]))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]